# web_accessible_resources can't access chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, requirejs, manifest

I'm developing an extension that uses **chrome.tabs.executeScript** to load an instance of **requirejs** from a file that has been placed in a closure to prevent it from polluting the global space. Let's call this closure **__MyGlobal**. This executes as expected.

I then use **chrome.tabs.executeScript** to run code in the same tab. This code is a basic __MyGlobal.require([*dependencies*],function(){}) call. This executes as expected.

It is the dependencies of that Require call that fail on their __MyGlobal.declare() calls.

The error is *Uncaught ReferenceError: __MyGlobal is not defined.*

---

Testing further if I enter __MyGlobal in the console it is not defined.
If I change the domain to my extension then the console shows __MyGlobal as expected.

[image]

I'm not sure how

In short

1. chrome.tabs.executeScript loads require.js
2. chrome.tabs.executeScript loads a require() statement with dependencies
3. require() file dependencies load (they're declared in web_accessible_resources)
4. require() dependencies had dependencies of their own (define statements)
5. the define statements cannot access requirejs

How can I get code loaded with **chrome.tabs.executeScript** and loaded as **web_accessible_resources** to play nice together? Are they in different domains? Thanks!

Comment: Content scripts run in [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). I think it'd be simpler for you to use [scriptTagContext](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/scriptTagContext) library.

Comment: I'm not running any content scripts.

Comment: executeScript runs content scripts.

Comment: require() runs page scripts.

Comment: So require injected as a content script can itself inject page scripts?

Comment: A page script is code that runs in a `<script>` element so yes. Take a look at scriptTagContext.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: This isn't a code problem. It is an environment question. I recognized there was some type of environment restriction. Not everything problem is a code problem, even if it has a code answer. I provided sufficient explanation of the roadblock to have wOxxOm solve the problem. It is sad to see a legitimate question with a great title marked down. I asked because I spent 2 hours searching and there was no good direction forthcoming. If you remove your negative mark, I'll take the time to sum up what I've learned to add value for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts injected with **chrome.tabs.executeScript** are "Content Scripts", meaning they are executed in their own javascript environment different than that of the website. They interact with the same DOM as the website.

requirejs works by creating script tags to load dependencies. Therefore the scripts loaded by requirejs are loaded into the page's javascript environment and not the extension's javascript environment.

You can read more about the way chrome extension environments are separated  [here. Programmatic-Injection and Execution-Environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) are both worth a read if your doing more than the most basic development for chrome.

The following sample, credit due to [wOxxOm (source here)](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/blob/master/scriptTagContext/scriptTagContext.js), can be added at the bottom of the require.js file to get requirejs to load via ajax when requirejs is running in its own javascript environment as a content script.

```
var legacyLoad = requirejs.load;
requirejs.load = function(context, moduleName, url){
    if(location.protocol === 'chrome-extension:'){//works for extension pages
        legacyLoad(context, moduleName, url);        
    }
    else {//works for content scripts
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET', url);
        x.onload = function() {
            if (x.status === 200) {
                // Run script in the current global context.
                try {
                    window.eval(x.responseText);
                } 
                finally {
                    context.completeLoad(moduleName);
                }
            } 
            else context.onScriptError(new Event('error'));

        };
        x.onerror = function() {
            ontext.onScriptError(new Event('error'));
        };
        x.send();
    }
}
```